# Can I mount a volume from a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

Is it possible to mount a volume from a Dockerfile? if not what is the best way to get this done?

I know you can do this using a normal Docker commands in the command prompt, but is there a better way to get this done?

Comment: You can mount a volume from a Dockerfile, you just can't specify the location -- so it that may or may not be helpful depending on your needs. The reason is the build should be independent of the host. As mentioned, you can copy files during the build, but if you want read/write you may need a different solution. You could use the API to get the location of the dynamically created volume, but I'm not sure of a use case where that would be better then specifying it on `run`. If you do have some unique use case, more detail would help.

Comment: It seems that [rocker](https://github.com/grammarly/rocker) might be helpful in such case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is **not** possible to do so during an image build.

I think the reason could be portability? I'm not quite sure here - will be nice if someone can explain this further.

But my guess is that if Docker would to allow users to mount volumes on  build then Docker will have to anticipate and handle different types of file systems, e.g Windows vs Unix. Also what if the directory path which it is supposed to be used for mounting does not exists on another host?

Anyway, I'm not quite sure what your use case is but you should be able to use the `ADD` or `COPY` commands to move files from your host's file system into the image during build and use the moved files for other purpose like installing etc.

**See:**
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/add

**Q:** So what is the best approach? 
**A:** I think there is no standard approach for mounting volume. I usually define my mounting in the `docker-compose` file.

**See:**
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/volumes-volume-driver

Comment: thanks for this, plus I have one more question, how do I mount the current folder as a volume for example I want to do something like this
docker run -i -t -v <currentfolder and sub contents>:/usr/TmpVolume ubuntu /bin/bash

Comment: @user3547774 I might try using the `\`pwd\`` command to run an expression to get the current working directory. Example: `docker run -i -t -v \`pwd\`:/usr/TmpVolume ubuntu /bin/bash`  Glad to help, let me know if this works for you

Comment: I tried this, did not work.  what does `pwd` do anyway?  It created a volume inside the container but the contents available on the host system were missing.

Comment: `pwd` is for print current working directory. If it doesn't work for you - probably just type `pwd` on commandLine and copy paste the current working directory path directly into your run command.

Comment: Silly question here. which operating system are you on? because pwd is a unix thing

Comment: alternatively... `docker run -i -t $(pwd):/usr/TmpVolume ubuntu /bin/bassh` tested on my machine and it works

Comment: @user3547774 let me know if it works for you as well. Also will appreciate it - if you can click on the tick and mark this as answered, only if you think that the initial question has been answered correctly. Thanks

Comment: I am using this on a windows machine and when I try

docker run -i -t $(pwd):/usr/TmpVolume ubuntu /bin/bash

I get the following error 

C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error parsing reference: "C:\\Tmp\\TmpVolume" is not a valid repository/tag.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.

Comment: `pwd` and `$(pwd)` are for Unix only. I'm not a windows person but you should be able to Google for 'how to get my current working directory path printed on command line'.

Comment: thanks everyone for the help, this is what finally worked
$currentPath = Convert-Path .
docker run -i -t -v ${currentPath}:/usr/TmpVolume ubuntu /bin/bash

Comment: Good job ! Glad that you solve the last bit yourself. Now give me the tick beside my answer already. :X Anyway, that is not important. as long as your issue is resolved

Answer (score 1):

Within the context of a `Dockerfile`, you have limited access to host resources, to the extent of what's needed to actually build the container's image. To illustrate, should you be able to mount host volumes, start containers or access their resources, that would probably equate to an image that can be built for you, in your current environment only.

If you really need host resources mounted as a volume for the duration of the build only, you might want to look into [Packr](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/docker.html). However, if you want the volume to be available when the container starts, then usually it's fine to somehow use `docker run --name=Foo $ARGS`.